# JPA Entity listener does not update @LastModifiedDate if only update is to an @ElementCollection field

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using `AuditingEntityListener` to update creation and last update date of the entity.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ENTITY_TABLE")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "MY_ELEMENTS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID"))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @BatchSize(size=100)
    private List<MyElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "CREATED_AT", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_AT", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

This works fine and updates `updatedAt` field to correct value:

```java
// Snippet 1
entity.setName("Entity 1");
entity.setElements(otherElements);
repository.save(entity);
```

However, when I update only `elements`, it still updates the `elements` field just fine, but it does not update `updatedAt` field:

```java
// Snippet 2
entity.setElements(otherElements);
repository.save(entity);
```

---

I have experimented a little with `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` hooks. `Snippet 1` triggers both hooks, while `Snippet 2` triggers neither. It is probably because `MY_ELEMENTS` table holds the relationship reference and there is actually no need to update anything in `MY_ENTITY_TABLE`. So, while, I cannot say that this behaviour is technically wrong, I believe it is logically wrong, at least in this case.

Do I have to manually update `updatedAt` field, or can I make JPA update it somehow?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis no, I have just omitted the configuration part. As I said, it works when I update a direct entity field, but doesn't work when I update ONLY the field with `@ElementCollection`.